# Using carto-vl to connect to local installation

Tags: javascript, carto, authentication, carto-vl

I'm trying to use carto-VL on a local instalation via docker. Everything works fine with carto.js v4 and airship, but when i try to use carto-vl it always gives errors and I can't access my datasets, here's what i'm doing:

```
carto.setDefaultConfig({
   serverURL: 'http://localhost/user/dev'
});
```

And it gives me this error

[image]

I've used the same code [here](https://carto.com/developers/airship/examples/#example-time-series-bridge) just changing the default config, i've tried to input as other thread sugested, but it gives me the same problem.

```
    const source = new carto.source.SQL(`select * from cordoba_catastro_simple where year > 1900 and year < 2018`, {
    user: 'dev',
    apiKey: 'default_public'
  }, {
    serverURL: 'http://localhost/user/dev'
  });
```

is there anything I can do to fix this?

edit:
I've tried to put the *8181* port on the serverURL but it gives the same error and the default auth is already set

Edit2: I've been digging into the carto-vl.js file itself, and found one of the sections that presents the problem

[image]

the **e** variable was supposed to have a stats item inside but it doesn't have it... can someone give me a hint of how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're changing not only the default config with `setDefaultConfig`, but also the default auth settings with `setDefaultAuth` correctly:

```
carto.setDefaultAuth({
   username: 'dev',
   apiKey: 'default_public'
});

carto.setDefaultConfig({
   serverURL: 'http://localhost/user/dev'
});
```

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287485/using-carto-vl-on-local-ubuntu-installation?rq=1) explains also that you may need to set the port in your `serverlURL` to `8181`.

Comment: using the port 8181 it gives the error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I had to expose the port on docker, it stoped giving the connection refused error but it keeps giving me the error mentioned in the image above